# why can't I create a method in the main method

Tags: java, oop

Hello I am  a want create method into main?
So this is code where i want crete method:

```
import  java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
class input{
public static void main (String args[]){
 void Randomises() {
    int writabledata;
   Random a=new Random();
    writabledata=a.nextInt();

}
}}
```

Comment: You can't create methods in methods. That's the rule.

Comment: You can't create method inside a method in Java.

Comment: Java specification like most other languages

Comment: You can't put methods inside other methods.

Comment: That's not how Java syntax works.  Methods are created on object, not on other methods.

Comment: This is not technically true...You can have an anonymous inner method inside a method.

Comment: @MrTi technically we are talking about method inside method, not method inside class that was created inside method

Comment: You can't declare a method directly in a method because you are programming in Java. Some languages allow nested methods or functions. Others don't. Java doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java does not allow to create methods within a method. This is a general rule and NOT specific to `main` method.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what you are looking for is to create additional static methods in your class:

```
public final class MyCommand {
    private MyCommand() {
      //
    }

    private static void releaseTheCatsOfWar() {
        System.out.println("Meow!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        releaseTheCatsOfWar();
    }
}
```

Of course, it would be better to do:

```
public final class MyCommand {
    private MyCommand() {
      //
    }

    private void releaseTheCatsOfWar() {
        System.out.println("Meow!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyCommand that = new MyCommand();
        that.releaseTheCatsOfWar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot create methods within methods in Java.
You can have it as an additional method of your class and call it form `main`.

Answer (score 0):

`public static void main` is not a class, it's a **method within class**. And your class is `input` (by the way, you should start class name with an uppercase letter, like `Input`), in which you define method `main`, from which your program starts working.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is *entirely pointless*, the closest way you would get to achieving your results is with the following:

```
public class Main {

    private static interface MethodMaker{

        void randomise();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MethodMaker methodMaker = new MethodMaker(){

            @Override
            public void randomise() {
                // DO SOMETHING

            }

        };

        methodMaker.randomise();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put method outside main ,, and just call it in main ,, like this :-

```
import  java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
class input{
  public static void main (String args[]){

                Randomises();

  }

  public void Randomises() {
    int writabledata;
    Random a=new Random();
    writabledata=a.nextInt();

       }

 }
```

Comment: For this to work, `Randomises` would need to be static.